# How to reload view asynchronously when carrierwave_backgrounder processing completes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using the [carrierwave_backgrounder](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder) gem in a Rails 3.2 app to handle background processing of image files and transfer to S3 via [queue_classic](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/queue_classic).

The gem sets a file_processing boolean to null when processing is complete, enabling the following:

```
#partial
<% if file.file_processing.nil? %>
 <%= image_tag file %>
<% else %>
 <p>processing</p>
<% end %>
```

I am using jquery to handle multiple file uploads ([jquery-fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)). When a file upload completes, it triggers an ajax response via create.js to render the partial.

This is fine, but means I end up with a long list of 'processing'.

Is there a callback I can take advantage of to reload the partial when background processing is complete?

Comment: there is a really cool gem called **[sync](https://github.com/chrismccord/sync)** take a look at it